# jersey 1 REST client with proxy

Tags: rest, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

How can I implement a jersey 1 client with a http proxy? I find many information on the net about jersey 2 but no jersey 1.
Any idea?

My client is currently created like this:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey Client + set proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415607/jersey-client-set-proxy)

Comment: and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385259/configure-proxy-to-jersey-client