# Is there a simple way to set a proxy host and port in Jersey 1?

Tags: java, jersey

Specifically, the version I am using is `Jersey 1.19`. Currently this is what I am doing:

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.getProperties().put(ApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_PROXY_URI, "myhost:myport");
```

However, this didn't work for me since I got an `UnknownHostException`:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException:
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The solution I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15253142/1993824) is what finally worked for me.